# Force a Window to Move / SetWindowPosition for another process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, hook

I have been working on a piece of recording software I developed on a game called L.A. Noire. The game is able to run in a windowed mode, but they seem to have not allowed window movement.

One thing I noticed when the game was lagging while starting up is that you can actually move the window, and it will stay where you put it. Digging more into Windows 7 I found out I can force the window menu with SHIFT + Right Click and confirmed that the window can indeed move around.

I grabbed the Win32 API calls `SetWindowPos` and implemented my C# code to "follow" a window. This works for other applications like uTorrent, Calc, and all other regular apps I have tried. However, it does *not* work for LA Noire. I have tried toggling the flags on `SetWindowPos`, such as the one that says don't deliver it to the `WndProc`, not showing/moving it, not resizing, etc.

I also tried other variants of `SetWindowPos` like `MoveWindow`, which didn't help move LA Noire but still worked with Calc etc.

What's the next logical step? Should I send `WM_MOVE` manually to the process or should I install a hook on the window?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "follow".  Are you saying that when you call `SetWindowPos` from your C# process to move the game window, it doesn't move?

Comment: @arx, correct. The "follow" feature I added makes it so when I move the "Capture Area" around it automatically moves the window to that spot.

Comment: It is possible that the game is running at a higher integrity level than your process, which would prevent you sending messages to it.  You could try running your process as admin.

Comment: I will check in the process manager, but I have UAC configured to always alert me and it never has for LA Noire.

Comment: For all we know, it could be a bug in your code (that remains inconsequential with other software). Please post the code you are using to move the window.

Comment: The code is open: https://github.com/krisives/GRemote/blob/master/Remote/UI/CaptureArea.cs#L263 It's an older project